# Why do my user permissions disappear when I switch between views?

Tags: python, django

I've created a HackerNews clone. Users are then given permissions to vote, submit a story etc. Each user, when logged in has a Session ID, which I've tested and I believe works just fine.

However, when I switch between views (from localhost/ to localhost/science for example), all those permissions seem to disappear.

Here is part of views.py:

```
def index(request, category_id=1):
    stories = top_stories(top=30)
    category = Category.objects.get(id = category_id)
    if request.user.is_authenticated():
        liked_stories = request.user.liked_stories.filter(id__in = [story.id for story in stories])
    else: 
        liked_stories = []
    return render(request, 'stories/index.html', {
        'stories': stories,
        'user': request.user,
        'liked_stories': liked_stories,
        'category': category,
        })
```

and here is my category function which basically sorts all stories of a particular category:

```
def category(request, category_name):
    template = 'stories/category.html'
    category = Category.objects.get(category_name = category_name)
    return render_to_response(template, {
        'category': category
        })
```

When I go to the localhost/{{category}} link, all the permissions such as voting and submitting a story seem to disappear.

Here is my base.html:

```
 <body>
        <div id = "content">
            <div id = "header">
                {% if user.is_authenticated %}
                    <div id = "user-info">{{user.username }} | <a href = "/story/">sumbit</a> | <a href = "/logout/">logout</a></div>

                {% else %}

                    <div id = "user-info"><a href = "/login/">Login</a></div>
                    <div id = "user-info"><a href = "/register/">Sign Up</a></div>

                {% endif %}
                <div id = "site-title"><h1><a href = "/">newsfeed</a></h1></div>
            </div>
            {% block content %}
            {% endblock content %}
        </div>
    </body>
```

index.html:

```
<ol>
{% for story in stories %}
    <li>
        <p class = "story-title">
        {% if user.is_authenticated and story not in liked_stories %}
            <a href = "/vote/" id = "story-vote-{{ story.id }}" class = "vote"><img src = "static/images/arrow.png" height = "20px" width = "20px"></a>
            <a href = "{{ story.url }}" id = "story-title-{{ story.id }}" target="_blank">{{story.title}} </a> <span class = "domain"> ({{ story.domain}}) </span>
        {% else %}
            <a href = "{{ story.url }}" style = "margin-left: 15px;" target="_blank">{{story.title}} </a> <span class = "domain"> ({{ story.domain}}) </span>
        {% endif %}
        </p>

        <p class = "story-info">
            {{story.points}} points by {{ story.moderator.username }} {{story.created_at|age}} | <a href = "{{ story.category.category_name }}/{{ story.id }}/"> comment </a>
            | <a href = "/{{ story.category.category_name }}/">{{ story.category }} </a>
        </p>
    </li>


{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

and category.html:

```
<ol>
{% for story in category.story_set.all %}
    <li>
        <p class = "story-title">
        {% if user.is_authenticated and story not in liked_stories %}
            <a href = "/vote/" id = "story-vote-{{ story.id }}" class = "vote"><img src = "static/images/arrow.png" height = "20px" width = "20px"></a>
            <a href = "{{ story.url }}" id = "story-title-{{ story.id }}" target="_blank">{{story.title}} </a> <span class = "domain"> ({{ story.domain}}) </span>
        {% else %}
            <a href = "{{ story.url }}" style = "margin-left: 15px;" target="_blank">{{story.title}} </a> <span class = "domain"> ({{ story.domain}}) </span>
        {% endif %}
        </p>

        <p class = "story-info">
            {{story.points}} points by {{ story.moderator.username }} {{story.created_at|age}} | <a href = "{{ story.id }}/"> comment </a>
            | <a href = "/{{ story.category.category_name }}/">{{ story.category }} </a>
        </p>
    </li>
{% endfor %}
</ol>
```

Is there anything that I'm missing that would rectify this issue?
Also, if you need any other files just let me know in the comments. 
Luca

Answer (score 3):

The index view works because you are including the `user` in the template context. If you have the [auth context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#django-contrib-auth-context-processors-auth) enabled (it is by default), then you don't actually need to include the user in the template context, because you are using the [`render`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render) shortcut.

```
return render(request, 'stories/index.html', {
    'stories': stories,
    'liked_stories': liked_stories,
    'category': category,
    })
```

The `category` view is not working because you are using `render_to_response`, and you have not explicitly included the `user` in the template context.

You can make it work with `render_to_response` by including a `context_instance` (see [the docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/shortcuts/#render-to-response)), but the easiest fix is to use the `render` shortcut for your category view as well.

```
return render(request, template, {
    'category': category
    })
```

Comment: That worked! I just have one other issue now where the arrow imgs aren't showing up in the localhost/category view. Do I fix this by including the 'liked stories' if statement from the index function in the category function?

Comment: Yes, if your template refers to `liked_stories`, then you need to add it to the template context in the view. If you find that you use a variable like `liked_stories` on every page, you might want to create your own [template context processor](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/api/#subclassing-context-requestcontext).

Comment: I tried adding the additional variables to the category function but keep getting errors. How would you suggest the category function look?

Comment: I don't think it will help you learn if I write the category function for you. If you get stuck, maybe ask a new question and show the errors you are getting. You might find it easier if you do `stories = category.story_set.all()` in the view, rather than doing the loop `{% for story in category.story_set.all %}` in the template. Then you'll have access to the stories in the view, and you can generate `liked_stories`.